# WP Debug set to true but still wsod

Tags: debug, wp-debug

I'm trying to do my first wordpress plugin, and I've added this on my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

but i still have white screen of the dead...

Comment: Enabling debugging won't prevent errors, but it should hopefully provide information that will let you track down the errors. _What is in the log file?_

Comment: If you are testing on local machine using LAMP or WAMP or XAMP, make sure the PHP setting display errors is enabled.

Comment: @Shazzad error display is kinda being explicitly disabled in question there :)

Comment: this is the problem: I've no debug.log file in wp-content directory